# Using titlepage to make a thesis cover page

Tags: titles, warnings

I'm trying to create the cover page for my thesis in LaTeX using `titlepage`, but I got some trouble. The title page has to follow some fixed rules imposed by my college, so I don't have any chance for customization.

This is what I produced...

```
\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
}%
\item[]}{\end{list}}

\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\definecolor{pantone}{RGB}{130,36,51}

\begin{titlepage}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{Immagini/Sigillo.pdf} \\[3cm]

    \begin{changemargin}{2cm}{-2cm}
        % Title
        {\myfont \huge \color{pantone} \fontsize{20pt}{1em} MapReduce Graph Algorithms}
    \end{changemargin}

    \begin{changemargin}{2cm}{-2cm}
        % Bottom of the page
        \vfill\noindent
        {\myfont \bfseries \color{pantone} \fontsize{10pt}{1em} Facoltà di Ingegneria dell'Informazione, Informatica e Statistica} \\
        {\myfont \bfseries \color{pantone} \fontsize{10pt}{1em} Corso di Laurea in Informatica}                                    \\
        {\myfont \fontsize{10pt}{1em} First Name Last Name}                                                                            \\
        {\myfont \fontsize{10pt}{1em} ID Number XXXXXXX}                                                                       \\ \\ \\
        {\myfont \fontsize{10pt}{1em} Advisor}                                                                                \\
        {\myfont \fontsize{10pt}{1em} Prof First Name Last Name}                                                                     \\ \\
        {\myfont \fontsize{10pt}{1em} Academic Year 2013/2014}                                                                   \\
    \end{changemargin}
\end{titlepage}
```

...and this is the [result page](http://docdroid.net/6vq5).

The left margin needs to be aligned with the S of the "Sapienza" logo. I have two problems with this code:

1. I got two `Underfull hbox` warnings: the first one occurs on the `\includegraphic` line, and the second one on the `\vfill` instruction.
2. I don't understand why the two coloured lines at the bottom of the page seem to be slightly right-indented with respect to the following lines.

Is there anyone that can give me some help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [`frontespizio`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/frontespizio) instead. The option `suftesi` looks very much like your desired output.

Comment: @DG' Well, I've deliberately avoided that package because it doesn't work for online compilers, which I'm using.

Comment: Which online compiler do you use? If `frontespizio` not installed, you can just upload the `frontespizio.sty` file to your project and you should be fine.

Comment: @Christoph The package is not missing, but it produces an intermediate file which I have to compile separately to make the frontespizio appear. The problem is just this intermediate file, which I cannot manage through ShareLaTeX, the online compiler I'm using...

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A titlepage and its margins are a constant pain for LaTeX users. But a titlepage is somehow static, the only moment you really need to care is when submitting the actual document.

Playing around with different margins in one document is possible, but somehow a pain and isn't really worth the trouble for a titlepage, though a titlepage is the first thing a reader will see.

Let's give it the appropriate attention and give it an extra document.

> [image: driuTitlepage]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{pantone}{RGB}{130,36,51}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=9cm,right=1cm,marginparwidth=0pt,top=7cm}
\begin{document}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont
        \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=2cm]{example-image.pdf}\par
        \vspace{3cm}
        {\huge\color{pantone}MapReduce Graph Algorithms\par}

        \vfill
        {\bfseries\color{pantone}Facolt\`a di Ingegneria dell'Informazione, Informatica e Statistica} \par

        {\bfseries\color{pantone}Corso di Laurea in Informatica}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
        {First Name Last Name}\par
        {ID Number XXXXXXX}\par
        {Advisor}\par
        {Prof First Name Last Name}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
        {Academic Year 2013/2014}\par
        \pagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Using package `pdfpages`, we can include the generated titlepage within the document.